# Consensus on the goalie 'hole' numbering in Hockey?

Tags: terminology, ice-hockey, scoring

In ice hockey, it seems fairly well agreed upon that there are 5 main 'holes' to aim for when shooting on the net. Upper left, lower left, upper right, lower right, and between the goalie's legs.

The last hole is always referred to as the '[5-hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-hole)'. But is there any agreement on the numbering of the other 4? A quick google image search shows all sorts of numbering schemes, which leads me to believe that, no, there is no agreement:

https://www.google.com/search?q=hockey+goal+5+hole&tbm=isch

Comment: I found [this discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Goaltender#Hole_numbering.3F) on a talk page  of a Wikipedia article. But it is rather brief.

Comment: I haven't heard of any other location referred to by a number. Just high glove, low glove, high stick-side, and low-stick side. That's relative to the goalie. Shot location can also be noted in reference to where the shot is going to relative to the net (i.e., short-side and far-side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, there is no agreement.**

You are accurate in your finding that there is no agreement. However in my experience it starts with one in the upper left and rotates clockwise down to the lower left to 4, with 5-hole added on.